# linq nested select new

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I've 2 db tables like as Family and Cars and have a class named Families. They connected eachother by a foreign key.

**Family**

ID | Surname | Address

**Cars**

ID | FamilyID | Name

A family can have multiple cars.

I want to bind this to a grid and I wrote this query:

```
var data = from d in Master.Connection.Familys.Where(x => some conditions).OrderByDescending(d => d.ID)
                       select new Families
                       {
                           Id = d.ID,
                           Surname = d.Surname,
                           Address = d.Address,
                           Cars = ""
                       };

foreach (var item in data)
            {
                var cr = Master.Connection.Cars.Where(x => x.FamilyID == item.ID);
                if (!cr.Any()) continue;
                foreach (var crItem in cr)
                {
                    item.Cars += crItem.Name + ", ";
                }
            }

public class Families
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Grid filled by data. However Cars column is empty. How can I do this in the first query? Or, is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: Did you define a `Cars` property on your `Family` database model?

Comment: No. Cars property is in Families class. Grid should be filled by Families object.

Comment: You should call .ToList() on your cr variable to avoid double enumeration with .Any() and the foreach loop. I would go even further and remove the .Any() check unless there is more logic between it and your foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var data = from d in Master.Connection.Familys.Where(x => some conditions).OrderByDescending(d => d.ID)
                   select new Families
                   {
                       Id = d.ID,
                       Surname = d.Surname,
                       Address = d.Address,
                       Cars = ""
                   };


data.ForEach(f => f.Cars = String.Join(",", Master.Connection.Cars.Where(x => x.FamilyID == item.ID).Select(cr => cr.Name).ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your linq is returning `IEnumerable<T>` which is *Lazy* by design. In other words, when your first linq is executed, it doesn't fetch the data immediately. The data is actually fetched when it is used for the first time. As a side-effect, `item.Cars += crItem.Name + ", ";` is getting overwritten. A possible workaround is to add a `.ToList()` to fetch the data immediately.

```
var data = Master.Connection.Familys
    .Where(x => some conditions)
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.ID)
    .Select(d => new Families
                   {
                       Id = d.ID,
                       Surname = d.Surname,
                       Address = d.Address,
                       Cars = ""
                   })
    .ToList();
```

**Update**
Your code is making multiple calls to the database in `var cr = Master.Conn ... item.ID);` which is totally unnecessary. Instead you can use `GroupJoin` as follows:

```
var data = Connection.Families   //main table
                .Where(x => some conditions)
                .GroupJoin(Connection.Cars   //left outer join
                    , f => f.ID   //join condition
                    , c => c.FamilyID // join condition
                    , (f, c) => new {Family = f, CarNames = c.Select(o => o.Name)})
                    .OrderByDescending(d => d.Family.ID)
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(o => new Families
                    {
                        Id = o.Family.ID,
                        Surname = o.Family.SurName,
                        Address = o.Family.Address,
                        // Check possible null from left join
                        Cars = o.CarNames.Count() > 0 ? o.CarNames.Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b) : string.Empty
                    })                    
                .ToList();
```

**PS:** Don't use `.Join()` as suggested by tbean because `.Join()` will produce *INNER Join* not a *LEFT OUTER Join*.

Comment: Thanks for your support but the solution is very very slow. There ara thousands of families and cars.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
   private IQueryable<Family> GetFamilys()
    {
        return Master.Connection.Familys;
    }

    private IQueryable<Car> GetCars()
    {
         return Master.Connection.Cars;
    }

    public List<Families> FillFamilies()
    {
      var list = (from family in GetFamilys()
                   join car in GetCars() on family.ID equals car.familyID 
                   into groupJoin from subcar in groupJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new Families
                  {
                   Id = family.ID,
                   Surname = family.Surname,
                   Address = family.Address,
                   Cars = subcar?.Name ?? String.Empty
                  }).ToList();
       return list;
     }
```

Comment: `.Join()` will produce *INNER Join* not a *LEFT OUTER Join*. So, if a family do not have a car, that family will be excluded. Also, you solution does not concatenate the car names as the OP's code does. Please check my updated answer with a `GroupJoin()` version.

Comment: Still you need to concatenate the car names.

Comment: This is not getting all of cars. Is there a way to get all of them?